# How do you print a line that filtered results are on?

Tags: python, readline

I'm trying to find a value from a txt that contains 2 words in a single line, the first word has to have a length longer than 10.
I want my result to be printed with
result and the line that my result is on.

I can find a value that first word is len>10 , however I can't print the line number that my result is on, I've tried `readline()`, and it comes with error like `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readline'`

Here is my code:

```
for line in open("birds.txt"):
  a = line.strip()
  word = a.split()
    if len(word[0])>10:
    c = word.readline()
print(a + " : " +c)
```

Comment: Note that here `word` is a list of `string`, because that's what `split()` returns, a list of strings, using a space as default separator.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your `if` statement. Is the `print()` statement supposed to be included in it?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
We also expect that you have looked up the error message, and interpreted it with respect to your code.  That error message is clear enough: you tried to `readline` from a list; there is no such method.  `readline` is a file method -- but you already have a loop the reads the lines for you.  What did you expect that line of code to do for you?

Comment: Use `enumerate()` to get line numbers along with lines. `for line_number, line in enumerate(open("birds.txt"), 1):`

Comment: `word.readline()` makes no sense. `word` isn't a file.

Comment: What is there in ```birds.txt```

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons **not** to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code would look like :
use `with` as a context manager so that the opened file would be closed at the end of operations ( in your case you're not closing the file , it's a bad practice).
To get the index AND the content at the same time you should use `enumerate`.
finally if you're using python > 3.6 you should use string formatting instead of concatenation since it's clearer and could lead to performance gains.

```
with open("birds.txt") as f:
    for index,line in enumerate(f):
        words = line.strip().split()
        if len(words[0])>10:
            print(f'{index} : {words[0]}')
```